# Make div height 100% in a table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I make div inside a cell table 100% height when the row is stretched by word wrapping in another cell.

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3v4wz030/8/) I want to have the div in the second cell to fill the whole cell (100% of height).

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
td div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        xxx
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need the background color to cover the entire cell, you can just set it on the `td` rather than `div`.

```
td:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

If you really need to make the `div` to cover the cell, you can try using the `position` tricks. Note, this approach only works when there is less data in the second cell.

```
td {
  position: relative;
}
td:last-child div {
  background-color: green;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zd09Lco/)**

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: really bad solution. if absolute div will be bigger then table cell - content will fall out http://jsfiddle.net/9p58gLhg/

Comment: @godblessstrawberry - you could use overflow:auto; to fix that issue.

Comment: @SolidSnake for which element and how that suppose to help?

Comment: @godblessstrawberry - put it on div, and it'll be scrollable content if it exceeds the width/height.

Comment: here's what I did: <td style="padding: 0; position: relative;"><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; overflow: auto;"> no need for left and top properties.

Answer (score 6):

**edit**

As mentioned in the comments below, my first approach `display: inline-block` did not work in firefox.

As **progysm** mentioned, using `tr, td{height: 100%}` works well on all browsers, see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3v4wz030/61/

```
td div {
    background-color: green;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
 tr, td { height: 100%; }
```

**Code below here does not work in firefox, I failed on my first attempt**

Just add `display: inline-block` see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3v4wz030/39/

```
td div {
    background-color: green;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: in my browser (firefox), I need to put tr, td { height: 100%; } with the td div { height: 100%; } no inline-block required.

Comment: `tr, td { height: 100%; }` actually doesn't work for me (not event the fiddle - tried Chrome and IE11). `inline-block` works but @Pangloss answer (position tricks) works better for my case because it fills the whole cell even when the cell has some padding.